# How does GoLang's map correlate to ClickHouse's AggregateFunction

Tags: go, clickhouse, open-telemetry

I am a Javascript developer with almost no experience in GoLang. I am trying to get into OpenTelemetry which is why I have been going through Uptrace's codebase to understand how telemetry data is handled on the backend.

I came across a code snippet which I could not really understand.

It's this [line](https://github.com/uptrace/uptrace/blob/3d4b8ac9180e70b49ed5975e33f6f11e231f5459/pkg/metrics/measure.go#L30). The `Message` struct has a `map` field that correlates to ClickHouse's `AggregateFunction(quantilesBFloat16(0.5), Float32)`

```
type Measure struct {
   ...
   Histogram map[bfloat16.T]uint64 `ch:"type:AggregateFunction(quantilesBFloat16(0.5), Float32)"`
   ...
}
```

`Measure`s are inserted [here](https://github.com/uptrace/uptrace/blob/3d4b8ac9180e70b49ed5975e33f6f11e231f5459/pkg/metrics/measure.go#L50).

```
func InsertMeasures(ctx context.Context, app *bunapp.App, measures []*Measure) error {
    _, err := app.CH.NewInsert().
        Model(&measures).
        ModelTableExpr("?", app.DistTable("measure_minutes_buffer")).
        Exec(ctx)
    return err
}
```

I am unable to understand how a key and value maps to `Float32`. Is the key being saved or the value?

What I have tried:

- Looking into ClickHouse table's `histogram` column, but the values are gibberish.
- Turned on debugging in Uptrace to view the queries and checked `query_log` table in CH, but it does not display the values.
- Tried building Uptrace from source after adding few logs but no success.

If someone can throw some light on this it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

AggregateFunction is a cool data type in ClickHouse - it keeps track of a computed value but allows you to add more values to it. For example, you can keep track of an average of values - which is more than just one number if you are going to add more values: the AggregateFunction needs to maintain both a running total and the count of values.

A 50% quantile is similar - you need to maintain a bunch of values to compute an intermediate 50th percentile. I'm not familiar with the Go, but I assume that is why it's using a map - to maintain these same values of AggregationFunction.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of AggregateFunctions, but I am still confused if its the map's key that is being aggregated or the map's value.

Comment: The values are aggregated. I don't know what the keys are actually - you might have to read the source code and see how it's implemented under the hood.